# Flash Logging API

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

Can anyone recommend a good (AS3) logging API for Flash/AIR/Flex?  I need something to capture and record mouse and keyboard events in addition to coded events.  Preferably something well documented/supported. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Thunderbolt](http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/). It allows you to see your log results in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

I developed and manage Loggee!, a Flash/Flex Logging Tool: http://davidbuhler.org/loggee-flex-logging-tool/

Answer (score 0):

You must see http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4flash/

with no more.... 
bye bye

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Arthropod](http://arthropod.stopp.se/) if you are looking for a development tool (this wasn't very clear in your question), if it's to log your client's behavior, I'm not aware of any tool sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I always end up writing my own logging solutions. They generally are very simple compared to the rest of the project, and by writing my own I can tailor it exactly to what I need. Whereas using a pre-built one, always seems like either it is too over-engineered and complex to use, or it's too simple and lacking a couple features I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Log5F](http://log5f.wordpress.com) logging utility for ActionScript 3.0