# Need help debugging an unknown anonymous method runtime error in flash

Tags: flash, debugging, anonymous-methods

I am running a large flash application that makes heavy use of anonymous methods for events. I  have an anonymous method that has a type 1010 error, that is caught by my uncaught exception handler. This error is encountered by users, I have never managed to catch it in the debugger.

I use some tricks to get the callstack, so I can find the bad code, but all I know is that MethodInfo-XXX is the function with the error, where XXX is some number. Is there a way I can track that back to a specific code block so I can fix this issue? MethodInfo-XXX is the label created by flash for this anonymous method.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to check the stack trace that flash generates when an error occurs at run-time (the window that pops up with the buttons continue and dismiss). Then look for the first known method (one you wrote) and start from there.

Another useful method is to put some logging code in suspicious methods. Here are some ideas:

- [Flash Logging API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234180/flash-logging-api)
- [Dealing with runtime errors in the Flash player](http://www.novio.be/blog/?p=482)
- [Runtime errors](http://www.foundation-flash.com/tutorials/runtimeerrors/)

Also refer to the question [Error 1010 in ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910233/error-1010-in-actionscript) for your specific error code.